# IN selelenium webdriver how to configure mail after pom run failed test cases .send me the detailed program clearly

Tags: java

IN  selenium web driver how to configure mail after pom run failed test cases .send me the detailed program clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the maven postman plugin - http://doc.fortysix.ch/maven/maven-postman-plugin/surefire-mail.html